# How to display an HTML table in two columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

In view I have table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
     ....
</table>
```

I want to see next result in view:

```
table_row_1 | table_row_2 
table_row_3 | table_row_4 
table_row_5 | table_row_6 
etc.
```

Comment: The table would change it's layout when resizing the window? When increase window's with or decrease it's height?

Comment: Yes. I want do it. Ideal solution will be next: if window small - 1 column. if window large - 2 or 3 columns

Comment: Both, window's width and height would affect the table? Or only one of them?

Comment: Only width would affect.

Comment: ...why not just use two tds per row? We need to see your markup to know why it isn't doing that already... because that's how HTML tables work: they display exactly as you design them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```css
table, tr, td, thead, tbody {display: block!important;}
tr {float: left!important; width: 50%!important;}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
     <tr><td>1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>2</td></tr>
     <tr><td>3</td></tr>
     <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

I used `!important` because we most likely have to overrule Twitter Bootstrap (according to your class names). It would be better to NOT use `!important` and copy the Bootstrap classes/declarations (and make them slightly more specific), but this is just for simplicity and to prove this solution works.

Comment: !important is not a catch-all that guarantees your code will work. Specificity and _other_ uses of !important also come into play. It's best to not use it unless you _know_ it is needed, which it sounds like you don't in this case.